# Programming convention on Anonymous Class vs Implementing Interface

Tags: java, android, interface, anonymous-class

**From the android development perspective**, while you are programming which way do you prefer to implement for listener? Or which way do you think is the best for readable code? I gave two example about these things but think more complex classes such as which has more than one Listener:)

First example which is an Anonymous Class:

```
public class SenderReceiverActivity extends Activity {

Button cancelButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sending);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Second example which is implementing interface :

```
public class SenderReceiverActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button cancelButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sending);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: +1 for the well-asked question. However, you should know that there are many similar question on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 2nd approch is good as

1- you can handle multiple Views click at one place...

2- it make code shorter and easy to read..

3- it is easy in maintenance.

4- if you are using the Base Activity like concept  in your project then it is also useful.

Comment: Moreover, I think implementing interface within Activity also shows which listener are you interested in at a first sight.

Answer (score 4):

if you have single button then first approch  is right because there are no any complexity in your code but when `you have many button then second is more clear ,just one onClick method for many buttons and check id of button using v.getId()`

But there are no any change in functionality both are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there isn't really much differences between both except one: in second case you have access to `onClick(View v)` method from outside the class.

If it comes to me I prefer first approach, because not often more than one component have at the same time the same behaviour on click.

Comment: I think it won't be a good practice to invoke such methods which are system-like methods(I'm talking about android case). If you need to call these kind of method explicitly something should be wrong. However your suggestion showed another aspect of implementing interface. Thanks :)

Comment: I did not say that I would do that. I only said there is such possibility =]